# IntelliJ IDEA Keymap

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

How can I make the Home key move the caret to the beginning of the current line?  I am aware of the Keymap setting "Move Caret to Line Start".  I have re-mapped this to Home.
But this actually seems to move the caret to the start of the text on the line, not the start of the line (i.e. column 1).  Pressing Home again will move it to the start of the line.

I have also tried using the IdeaVim plugin.  In my case, the full VIM key mappings are not desired, but I did notice that it is capable of making Home move the caret to the start of the line, which to me implies that it's possible.

In NetBeans, there are different commands for "start of line" and "start of text on line".  I haven't yet been able to find that with IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Smart Keys | **Home moves caret to first non-whitespace character** -> disable.